# PHP: Why is my session variable not set here?

Tags: php

i tested my code on localhost and it's working fine, on my actual server the value of $_SESSION['regID'] isn't set in Buttons.php but it is set in checklogin.php here's the code any help would be greatly appreciated

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

?>
<?php

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM appusers WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

$sqlreg="SELECT * FROM appusers WHERE username='$myusername' ";
$resultreg=mysql_query($sqlreg);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$countreg=mysql_num_rows($resultreg);

if($countreg==1) {
    echo "success";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultreg))
    {
        echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['regID'];
        echo "<br>";
        $_SESSION['regId'] = $row['regID'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_SESSION['regId'];

        header("location:http://mywebsite.com/project/Buttons.php");
    }
}
else {
     echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**Buttons.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

Print_r($_SESSION);

?>
<html>

<?php 

$regID=$_SESSION['regId'];
echo $regID; 

if(isset($_SESSION['regId']))
echo "success";
else
echo "failed";


?>
</html>
```

Comment: please only store a hashed password and not in plain text

Comment: also it should be print_r and not Print_r

Comment: Also dont use mysql_* :)

Comment: You are calling `session_start` twice - this shouldn't be a problem though. Keep in mind that there is also an **unclosed** output buffer in there, this may hide all your output.

Comment: basically I would re factor all the code in order to try and ascertain where the error is occuring

Comment: Sidenote: `ob_start();` goes above `session_start();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you explain why (just interested)? I don't see any flushing of the buffers either

Comment: Make sure you have a field name `regID` in your table; keep in mind PHP is case-sensitive and there is different between `regID` and `redId`

Comment: 9 times out of 10, is where `ob_start();` is located. `session_start();` could qualify as output, therefore `ob_start();` should "theoretically" be placed first. @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get any PHP errors ?
Try add this to your scrpit

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: this is what i got: Warning: Unknown: open(/var/php_sessions/sess_392131e6d0e036d65634fb0836a491e7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/php_sessions) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: has the webserver process got write permissions to that directory?

Comment: Yes, probably. Show your chmods for /var/php_sessions

Comment: i'm sorry im very new to this, the webserver permissions only displays a number (644) i'm using ipage as a webserver

Comment: Firstly, You have to check if /var/php_sessions exist.
Check this solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843417/php-session-start-error-on-server-side#comment4083091_3843430

Comment: Are you able to modify php.ini?

Comment: Is the location `/var/php_sessions/` coming from your application, or from the system? Different systems put things like session files in different places, so that may work on one server but not another. See if `/var/php_sessions/` even exists, and if it does, do you have permissions to access it?

Comment: @jakon and Nicholas King thank you both for your help i followed the link and it solved my problem

Comment: nothing was wrong with the code, the ipage server didn't have the permission for sessions, so i added the permission following the steps in the link,thanks again for your help :)!