# Installing issues with installing ips forums

Tags: php, html, forums

I'm getting an error after uploading my ips forums to my webhost through FileZilla.

This is on the install page for the forum page:

```
session_start(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_cac0f0b2508ab8e99ba45a6392b9473e, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: pls check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843417/php-session-start-error-on-server-side

Comment: Please, check permissions for that folder. But it looks like a configuration problem in your server, so I would suggest you to tal to the IT guys